# Postgresql - Can we create streaming and logical replication replication from same server

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6

I have a postgresql setup with 1 master and 3 slaves. Now I want to setup a replication for only one database to reporting server.

#### My problem statements:

1. I can't use bucardo (no approval for creating triggers on prod
   tables)
2. pglogical only works on Master node.(the publisher).
3. I want  to replicate from slave (this is my end goal)

Comment: Upgrade to v10 or better v11 and use logical replication. There is no reason to use a physical standby as logical replicatoin source. Use the primary.

Comment: Will this  v10 has this feature?

Comment: No, a physical standby cannot (and need not) be a logical replication primary server (that wouldn't work with trigger based replication either). But with v10 you don't need pglogical for logical replication.

Comment: Thats great thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this one? I was struck with the same question.